# Spark Task not serializable (Array[Vector])

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Spark, and I'm studying the "Advanced Analytics with Spark" book. The code is from the examples in the book. When I try to run the following code, I get `Spark Task not serializable` exception.

```
val kMeansModel = pipelineModel.stages.last.asInstanceOf[KMeansModel]
val centroids: Array[Vector] = kMeansModel.clusterCenters

val clustered = pipelineModel.transform(data)

val threshold = clustered.
      select("cluster", "scaledFeatureVector").as[(Int, Vector)].
      map { case (cluster, vec) => Vectors.sqdist(centroids(cluster), vec) }.
      orderBy($"value".desc).take(100).last
```

Also, this is how I build the model:

```
def oneHotPipeline(inputCol: String): (Pipeline, String) = {
    val indexer = new StringIndexer()
        .setInputCol(inputCol)
        .setOutputCol(inputCol + "_indexed")

    val encoder = new OneHotEncoder()
        .setInputCol(inputCol + "_indexed")
        .setOutputCol(inputCol + "_vec")

    val pipeline = new Pipeline()
        .setStages(Array(indexer, encoder))

    (pipeline, inputCol + "_vec")
}

val k = 180

val (protoTypeEncoder, protoTypeVecCol) = oneHotPipeline("protocol_type")
val (serviceEncoder, serviceVecCol) = oneHotPipeline("service")
val (flagEncoder, flagVecCol) = oneHotPipeline("flag")

// Original columns, without label / string columns, but with new vector encoded cols
val assembleCols = Set(data.columns: _*) --
  Seq("label", "protocol_type", "service", "flag") ++
  Seq(protoTypeVecCol, serviceVecCol, flagVecCol)
val assembler = new VectorAssembler().
  setInputCols(assembleCols.toArray).
  setOutputCol("featureVector")

val scaler = new StandardScaler()
  .setInputCol("featureVector")
  .setOutputCol("scaledFeatureVector")
  .setWithStd(true)
  .setWithMean(false)

val kmeans = new KMeans().
  setSeed(Random.nextLong()).
  setK(k).
  setPredictionCol("cluster").
  setFeaturesCol("scaledFeatureVector").
  setMaxIter(40).
  setTol(1.0e-5)

val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(
  Array(protoTypeEncoder, serviceEncoder, flagEncoder, assembler, scaler, kmeans))
val pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(data)
```

I am assuming the problem is with the line `Vectors.sqdist(centroids(cluster), vec)`. For some reason, I cannot use `centroids` in my Spark calculations. I have done some Googling, and I know this error happens when "I initialize a variable on the master, but then try to use it on the workers", which in my case is `centroids`. However, I do not know how to address this problem.

In case you got interested [here](https://github.com/sryza/aas/blob/master/ch05-kmeans/src/main/scala/com/cloudera/datascience/kmeans/RunKMeans.scala) is the entire code for this tutorial in the book. and [here](http://kdd.ics.uci.edu/databases/kddcup99/kddcup99.html) is the link to the dataset that the tutorial uses.

Comment: What is the type of centroids?

Comment: It is `Array[Vector]`.